# Proper usage of "assessed" for delinquent bills

Tags: word-usage

> Delinquent bills will be assessed a USD 100 (United States Dollar One Hundred Only) **charge** if payment is not received within 7 days of the due date.

Is this the correct usage?

Or should the word "charge" be removed from the sentence?

> Delinquent bills will be assessed a USD 100 (United States Dollar One Hundred Only), if payment is not received within 7 days of the due date."

Comment: It does seem a cross-over usage; [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assess) has: **assess** (v trans) 3. to impose a tax or other charge on: _to assess members for painting the clubhouse_.  I'd expect 'Delinquent bills will attract a USD 100 (United States Dollar One Hundred Only) charge if payment is not received within 7 days of the due date.' or 'A USD 100 (United States Dollar One Hundred Only) charge will be levied on top of the debt  if payment is not received within 7 days of the due date.'

Comment: We (US) wouldn't use "attract", @EdwinAshworth, but we do use "incur".

Comment: Agree with @KristinaLopez. I'd expect "Delinquent bills will incur a ... charge ..." OR "A USD 100 ... charge will be assessed ..."

Comment: Another possibility is "Delinquent bills will be assessed "at" USD 100"

Comment: The agentive nature (or rather the not-very-agentive nature) of  'delinquent bills' leaves me not too happy about their incurring anything (though doubtless the usage is quite common in the US. But I've only found 20-odd examples for "delinquent bills incur".) All three dictionaries at TheFreeDictionary avoid any but more agentive subjects with 'incur'. Though I'd certainly opt for the more common verb usage in say 'Non-payment will incur a fine of ...', where there is a more direct coupling of cause and effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would understand what you meant in both cases, but it sounds incorrect to not use charge in this case. Furthermore, I don't think you would say that the bills are assessed charges; rather, the holders of the bills are assessed the charges.